# Can we execute a postgresql stored procedure in background

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL stored procedure which needs to process huge amount of data . The process can take 10 hour also. I am currently working with PostgreSQL 12.7.
My procedure is getting triggered from a JAVA asynchronous thread. I want to release the JAVA thread as soon as the call to procedure is triggered and not hold it for 10 hours and execute the procedure from PostgreSQL end (background process).
Is there any way to execute the procedure in background which is independent of the calling API?

Comment: You can make async [commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-async.html), there may be java library built using this feature of postgresql. For python, there is psycopg2.

Comment: https://github.com/vibhorkum/pg_background

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I am using Amazon RDS for postgres. It does not provide the extension for pg_background. Is there any other way in RDS postgres?